# missing 1 required positional argument: 'nums'

Tags: python

i am new at python and i was solving problems on leetcode but my code keep throwing this error `TypeError: Solution.removeDuplicates() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nums'` at line 6

Here's my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        return set(nums)            

nums = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]
ans = Solution.removeDuplicates(nums)
print(type(ans))
```

can anyone please help?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In your case you should remove self from functions argument

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(nums):
        return set(nums)            

nums = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]
ans = Solution.removeDuplicates(nums)
print(type(ans))
```

it will work in your case but it is a bad practice

you should **init** this class

class Solution(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    pass
def removeDuplicates(self,nums):
    return set(nums)
```

Comment: This is bad practice. If you are going to do this, make it a `staticmethod`.

Comment: i know its bad practice , i Should mention it

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the class before calling its methods.

```
In [1]: Solution().removeDuplicates(nums)
Out[1]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Code:

```
nums = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]
ans = Solution().removeDuplicates(nums)
print(type(ans))
```